# Trim a variable's value until it reaches to a certain character

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, substr, texttrimming

so my idea is like this..

```
var songList = ["1. somesong.mid","13. abcdef.mid","153. acde.mid"];
var newString = myString.substr(4); // i want this to dynamically trim the numbers till it has reached the .
```

// but i wanted the 1. 13. 153. and so on removed.
   // i have more value's in my array with different 'numbers' in the beginning

so im having trouble with this can anyone help me find a more simple solution which dynamically chop's down the first character's till the '.' ?

Comment: till the . after the number's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
var songList = ["1. somesong.mid","13. abcdef.mid","153. acde.mid"];
songList.forEach(function(value, i){
    songList[i] = value.replace(/\d+\./, ''); //value.substr(value.indexOf('.') + 1)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c08vya0o/)

Comment: no sorry i didn't make this clear.. i wanted to have the number's including the . cut out from the variable but i have variable's with different lengths so i wanted to find a more dynamic way of removing them

Comment: @AdarshHegde I think it does that `newString` will have a value of ` sometext.mp3` is that what you needed

Comment: sorry that was the point i didn't be specific.. i should edit this question and have some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string [`.match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to extract the part up to and including the first `.` as follows:

```
var newString = myString.match(/[^.]*./)[0];
```

That assumes that there *will* be a match. If you need to allow for no match occurring then perhaps:

```
var newString = (myString.match(/[^.]*./) || [myString])[0];
```

If you're saying you want to remove the numbers and keep the rest of the string, then a simple `.replace()` will do it:

```
var newString = myString.replace(/^[^.]*. */, "");
```